# How to share and keep dynamic libaries up to date?

Tags: ios, frameworks, xcode6

So I watched the whole video ("Building modern frameworks") [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/) and I still have some questions. The last 11 minutes is the actual demo if you want to watch it, but to sum up he creates a framework and then stops. He does not show how to share it or place it in other projects.

1.) In order to use the frameworks in other projects I have to import both the simulator framework and the device framework to work? Is that correct?

2.) Can I copy the actual framework out of the build folder to use in other projects?

3.) Is it possible to keep the framework up to date among different projects? Like change method A in the first project and the change is also visible in the second project?

4.) The guy from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=86cPaa3FrRg) has also an option for keeping pieces of code in sync with different projects. In short: He makes a project (framework) places all the code in it who should be the same in other projects. He then copies the framework in other projects and does not copy the framework in there, but just links it. Is this a good method? Will this be accepted by Apple?

Comment: Are we talking OSX or iOS?

Comment: Good question, forgot that, we are talking about iOS.

Comment: Then use `git submodule` to hold the framework source code.  When it changes, pull it and rebuild the app (where the framework Xcode project has been made a dependency of the app's Xcode project).

Comment: I did not know that exsisted, but it would be nice if it can be achieved with frameworks. Apple says it is possible, but they do not tell how to do it. If I look at `submodule` that probably will work, but I really wanted to try it with framework. You never know what Apple might add to it in the future.

Comment: I don't follow; it's got nothing to do with frameworks; it's simply a matter of keeping the Xcode project in a separate git repo and bringing it into other Xcode projects using `git submodule`.  It does not matter that it's a framework project at all.

Comment: @trojanfoe, Ok , so I looked around and did some reading on submodules and looked very promising. At first I did not got everything to work, but then I founded this page: http://thedragcave.com/tutorial-using-sub-projects-git-submodules-to-create-a-framework-in-ios/ . Very, very useful. The only problem is that when creating the project there is relatively much stuff to get it all working (prone for errors). Any ideas, of how to get around this? Is it possible to make a template from it?

Comment: What sort of "stuff" are you talking about?  Xcode project settings etc?  If you are linking against another (library) project then all you need to do is tell Xcode that the app project depends on the library project and it does everything else for you.  I don't even think you need to set the *Header Search Path*, but I might be wrong about that...

Comment: @trojanfoe, I am sorry, "stuff" is not very descriptive :) . In the link of my previous Comment , the author does two things 1.) Makes the Framework 2.) Makes the parent file. The part for the parent project involves quite some steps. I was wondering if you could shorten that by some bash script or make a project template of the project and use that every time.

Comment: Sorry I really don't have time.  I've got to mow the lawn and everything... and there's having a nap.  And then it'll be time to play Borderlands 2.

Comment: Just a little push in the right direction or something? Specific tools or something and of course you can give a reaction tomorrow too ;)

Comment: I don't think there is any way round it; I've never scripted anything in Xcode other than build steps (i.e. calling shell scripts). That would probably require using AppleScript and I've never used it.  I don't think there is *that* much to do to be honest.